# Create macro to generate getters for any class c++

Tags: c++, getter, preprocessor

Recently I started thinking how to generalize access to private data members through a generalized class/function by name. The reason is that I have a lot of private members and creating a getter for each one is bothersome. I tried to use preprocessor macros to do the following

```
#define RETURNS(...) -> decltype((__VA_ARGS__))  { return (__VA_ARGS__); }
#define GET(classname, name, funcname) auto funcname() RETURNS(classname->name);

class foo {
private: 
    int a = 1;
    std::vector<int> b = std::vector<int>(3, 1);
    std::string c = "pika-chuuu";
public:
    foo() = default;
    ~foo() = default;

    GET(this, a, getter);
};

int main(const int argc, char* argv[]) {

    foo obj;
    std::cout << obj.getter();
    return 0;
}
```

This one compiles, but is there a way I can create a getter in `foo`, which takes the name of a variable at run-time and returns `this->(name)`? Using this approach I can reduce the code for introducing getters, nevertheless the more data members there are, the more getters I need, but I would like to have one to get access to any data member by name. Do you have any suggestion of how can it be done?
I'm looking for a syntax like this:

```
#define RETURNS(...) -> decltype((__VA_ARGS__))  { return (__VA_ARGS__); }
#define GET(classname, name) RETURNS(classname->name);
class foo {
private: 
    int a = 1;
    std::vector<int> b = std::vector<int>(3, 1);
    std::string c = "pika-chuuu";
public:
    foo() = default;
    ~foo() = default;

    auto getter(auto x) GET(this, x);
};
```

Here `x` is the name I put as input, either `a`,`b` or `c`

Comment: A big dependence on getters is usually a sign that the design is lacking in abstraction. Have you tried to approach the problem from the other angle, questioning why you need so many of them?

Comment: @molbdnilo In my design a have a lot of members, which should be inaccessible by the user per se, so I would rather omit having them public. The getters I use return values or references to a const object so the user can't change them, but he may need a copy or reference to specific fields. One approach would be to pack all those parameters to a struct and make a getter to the struct, but this may become bothersome in the implementation to rewrite this->var to this->structname.var etc.

Comment: Having a lot of members is again a sign of a weakness in the design. And why would other actors need access to **all** of them? Perhaps some  members ought to be members of that other class instead? And, using macros is *hardly ever* the solution to a design problem. Simplifying the class more often is,

Comment: @BoP "Perhaps some members ought to be members of that other class instead?" you mean to define a struct to hold those data members I would need getter to? I'll try to look over the design if I could change it, separate the members onto other classes (3 classes inherit from a base class which has those members and getters). Bu in any case is there a way to define such a function?

Comment: *you mean to define a struct to hold those data members I would need getter to?* No, I mean that if some other class frequently needs to get some values, perhaps those values instead belong to that other class. Having some getters is ok, needing **many** getters is suspicious.

Comment: Have you considered making the data public and holding const references to `foo`?

Comment: I understand the concern, but that is not the case here. I need those data members in this class (which is a virtual base class), because there are methods directly relating to those members at the base class level adnt the getter were supposed to be a helpful tool for a user using this code as library if he wants to get direct access to those members outside a derived class scope. Nevertheless, right now I have ~8 getters which I suppose I can't change

Comment: @Caleth I did, but in my case the user may create an instance of a class, which is inheriting from foo (which in my case is much more complex) and changes the data members so the class needs to access those fields, but the user rather not. So I either keep the getters in case the user may need access to those fields outside the class or let him create a class inheriting from foo and let him declare getter himself if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Revision:

As **@HolyBlackCat** mentioned, there is no need to heap allocation, and you should use the `impl` class as object directly:

```cpp
class foo{
    struct foo_data
    {
        int i;
        std::string s;
    };
    foo_data data;
public:
    template<typename ... Args>
    foo(Args&& ... args)
    : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    foo_data const* operator->() const   // Returns a pointer to const data
    {
        return &data;
    }
};
```

Then to access the data:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto f = foo(3, "hello");
    std::cout << f->i << f->s;          // Accessing data, prints: "3hello"
    // f->i += 1;                       // Error: assignment of member in read-only object
}
```

Comment: That is actually an interesting solution. It might help after all, thanks!

Comment: in the case of member functions of foo, would the compiler "know" if i write this->i ? Would the operator be overloaded at that point? or would the operator only work outside the class scope for class instances, where the input would be specified?

Comment: @Qant123 I've updated the implementation, and you might want to use the new one instead. And Yes, you can use any member function within the class, including the overload `operator->`. However, the proper syntax would be `(*this)->i`

Comment: @Qant123 Also do note the job of the overloaded `operator->` is to return an immutable object. Since there shouldn't be a need to limit the mutability within the class, you should probably access the data directly with `data.i` within `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the code! Right now I'm sticking to simple getters (maybe even delete them if I find them unecessary) to omit rewriting every call to data members with this->data.something. But this might definetely come in handy sometimes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have any suggestion of how can it be done?

Why all the `decltype` and `->` and variadic macro with `__VA_ARGS__` and `RETURNS` and ... Just:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define DECL_GETTER(name) \
        auto get_##name() { return this->name; }

class foo {
private: 
    int a = 1;
    std::vector<int> b = std::vector<int>(3, 1);
    std::string c = "pika-chuuu";
public:
    DECL_GETTER(a)
    DECL_GETTER(b)
    DECL_GETTER(c)
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.get_a();
    f.get_b();
    f.get_c();
}
```

I would also add `const` overload when by it.

You may want to research [QT properties system](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/properties.html), that is basically like a more advanced version of this.

Subjective: TBH with such one macro you are making abstractions where they are not needed. Is it worth the time? It hides some obvious code with non-obvious macro, makes IDE "jump to definition" harder, makes maintenance and reasoning harder. Renaming variables with IDE features will be harder. Consider just writing those getters by hand verbatim - consider readable and clear code that is obvious on the first look, even when you have to sacrifice a little repetition and type `() { return` some more characters. Configure your IDE, so you can have "create a getter/setter for this member function" action to speed up your development (see for example QT Creator, it's one feature that is really nice there).

> is there a way I can create a getter in foo, which takes the name of a variable at run-time and returns this->(name)?

C++ is a language without [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming), so basically no, or it would require way more boilerplate code than it is worth.

Comment: The RETURNS macro was used in another place in the code and decltype(...) is remnant from using a C++11/14 compiler. I'll look into the QT properties, but if it is not possible to declare a macro/function like that then I'll stick to mu gettters I use right now

Comment: Anyhow, thank you very much! I see I also don't need to pass the class in the macro in this case, because I cannot declare the getter outside the class anyway